# react-redux useSelector hook disallows passing props directly to the selector

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I've just started playing with the new `useSelector` hook provided in `react-redux`.

I have always passed props directly in to my selectors like this:

```
mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
   return {
      user: userSelector(state, ownProps.userId)
   }
}
```

Is passing props directly into selectors considered an anti pattern?

If "No", then how can I achieve this with `useSelector`?

If "Yes", then what are the correct patterns to achieve this parameterisation of the selector?

Answer (score 8):

This is good practice to use `props` in selectors.

> The selector function does not receive an ownProps argument. However, props can be used through closure (see the examples below) or by using a curried selector.

`useSelector` accepts function with `state` argument. If you'll pass arrow function to `useSelector` you'll be able to access any variable in closure, including `props`.

This example is taken from [official documentation](https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks#useselector-examples)

```
import React from 'react'
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'

export const TodoListItem = props => {
  const todo = useSelector(state => state.todos[props.id])
  return <div>{todo.text}</div>
}
```

Also take a look at [stale props](https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks#stale-props-and-zombie-children) page in official documentation on how to avoid some mistakes with local `props` usage.

Comment: thanks! If the selector is more complicated than the naive example, e.g. a selector composed of multiple other selectors etc. do I have to create a new instance, close over props and memoize it in the component's function scope? This removes reselect from stack pretty much. Hmmm. Keen to see a more real world example of a composed and memoized selector if you're game!

Comment: you can still reference a more complex selector (such as a reselect combine selector in that callback)

`useSelector(state => someSelector(state, {id: props.id}}`